# How to scrape using Node js array of urls, each url from different ip?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request

i have array of urls and list of ip's,proxy.

```
urls = ['http://someurl1.com','http://someurl2.com','http://someurl3.com','http://someurl4.com'];
```

i need to scrape all of them with different ip's.

is it possible to do parallel?

can i get some examples with ip's and proxy?

Comment: Have you tried any of the available npm modules for web-scraping? Eg. https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-scraping

Comment: the main problem is change ip with each request and do it parallel. because in fact i have 100 urls in array :C

Comment: 100 isn't a big number I feel. Although, I'm not aware how long "scraping" would take.